# Antibot with PHP and JQuery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I am building a simple antibot for my email form. 
This is a code which makes a problem:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $a = rand(1, 10);
    $b = rand(1, 10);
    $antibot = $a + $b;
    $_SESSION["antibot"] = $antibot;
?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sendEmail").click(function(){
            var antibot = $("#antibot").val();
        $.post(
            "test.php",
            {antibot: antibot}, 
            function(data){
                    alert(data.info);
            }, 
            "json"
            );
        );
    );
);
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tr><td>AntiBot: <?php echo $a . ' + ' . $b;?> = </td><td><input type='text' id='antibot' /></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan='2'><input type='button' id='sendEmail' value='Send'/></td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And my test.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $antibot = $_POST["antibot"];
    $data = array();
    if(isset($_SESSION["antibot"])){
        if($_SESSION["antibot"] == $antibot){
            $data["info"] = "Session is isset and answer is right!";
        }
        else{
            $data["info"] = "Session is isset but answer is NOT right!";
        }
    }
    else{
        $data["info"] = "Session is NOT isset!";
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I constantly get this info: "Session is isset but answer is NOT right!"
If you can see $_SESSION["antibot"] in test.php is setted but value is `""` no matter what I type in input field `#antibot`!

I do not understand why this is happening, please can someone tell me where the problem is and how can I fix it?

Comment: shouldn't you be checking isset($antibot) also ?

Comment: That's ok. I checked so many times, only problem is that $_SESSION["antibot"] has a blank value.

Comment: I have gone through your code and this is what i understood first of all you generate two random numbers and sum it up and save it as antibot in session. Then in the form user enters some value in the antibot field. When the user submit the page values are send to test.php.And in the test.php you are matching session value and user entered antibot value. Is that correct ?

Comment: That's right, I checked all page and all are properly send(#antibot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this code here:
http://onlinephpfunctions.com/stackoverflow/11981309/

And it seems completely valid.

I had to make some modifications to your javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sendEmail").click(function(){
            var antibot = $("#antibot").val();
        $.post(
            "test.php",
            {antibot: antibot}, 
            function(data){
                alert(data.info);
            }, 
            "json"
           )
    })

})
    </script>
```

After that it was working fine. It may just be some problems with cookies in your browser, or an error in your PHP config so sessions wont be stored right. Please check this, your code works OK, as you can see in the demo.

Comment: Thanks, I tryed in Chrome, IE, FF and the problem exists, so the problem is server? But thats strange, because when I echo $_SESSION["antibot"] on index.php I got the right value but problem is in mail.php somehow it wont work on my server, I will write to the hosting support.

Comment: You should check it by using two files. In the first file you set a session variable, in the second you echo it. If the second file does not returns the variable there is something wrong. Also be sure test.php is on the same server and same account...

Comment: Oo men this is so anoying! On index.php echo good, on other file echo good but wont check test.php again the same problem! Why?! :( :( Is maybe somehow ajax problem?